# removing class from svg images, vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i have a problem removing specific class from svg images, i have simplified my code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raminSafari/zw5kL20u/32/)

when i click on the image it gets particular class but i cant remove that very class by reset button

html

```
  <div id="app">
      <img src = "https://simplemaps.com/static/demos/resources/svg-library/svgs/world.svg" class = "img-fluid" style= "width: 200px;" @click = "tap($event)">
    </div><!-- there are some images, just to clarify, I simplified my code -->
    <!-- when i click on image it gets particular class but i cant remove that very class by reset button -->
    
    <button @click = "reset">
    reset
    </button>
```

css file

```
.colorFilter{
   filter: invert(43%) sepia(96%) saturate(1237%) hue-rotate(88deg) brightness(58%) contrast(139%);
}
```

vue

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   
  },
  methods: {
    tap(event){
            event.target.classList.add('colorFilter');
    },
    reset(){
        const imgz =  document.getElementsByTagName('img');
      imgz.classList.remove('colorFilter');// i cant reset the images
    }
  }
})
```

thank you

Comment: you can also use dynamic class binding see this reference for more information https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Comment: thanks for your answer @Tanvir but according to document if i assign true to isActive all of the images would get that class, but i want only that clicked image get that class not all of the images

Comment: assign each image a unique id and send ut over the method parameter and then check is your passing id == that image id and isActive is true or not ,,,,if condition is met then assign class otherwise not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using document.getElementsByTagName which returns an array of elements.

Use document.getElementsByTagName('img')[number] to get a specific element from that list.

Comment: there are several images and i want to remove that specific class from all of them

Comment: I took a better look at your fiddle. Your button has to be inside the "#app" container since that is the one that vue is listening on. Second of all if you want to remove that specific class from multiple elements then you could use a for loop for that. (use document.querySelectorAll('img.colorFilter') to get the elements)

Comment: thanks man, i remove class with for loop, thank you very much,

this.tags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');// i intialize a vriable named tags in data


for(var i = 0; i < this.tags.length; i++){
            this.tags[i].classList.remove('colorFilter');
          },,,,  i should remove the class one by one, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`<button @click="reset">reset</button>` is outside the `<div id="app">` and `@click` is shothand for `v-on:click` that's why vue doesn't know when the button was clicked

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    mapActive: false
  },
  methods: {
    tap(){
            this.mapActive = !this.mapActive
    },
    reset(){
        this.mapActive = false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.colorFilter{
   filter: invert(43%) sepia(96%) saturate(1237%) hue-rotate(88deg) brightness(58%) contrast(139%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img src = "https://simplemaps.com/static/demos/resources/svg-library/svgs/world.svg" :class="['img-fluid', { 'colorFilter': mapActive }]" style= "width: 200px;" @click = "tap()">
  <button @click = "reset">
reset
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Aslam, but when  i click on an image which triggers tap method all of the images turn into green, i want only clicked image to become green not all of them but with reset button i want to remove colorFilter class from all of the images, i made some changes to my fiddle